# Div wont float on the right side of the browser

Tags: css, html

I've got two sets of buttons inside a div, one div needs to float on the left side of the broswer, the other to the right. They should be fixed so they will never move. The only problem I am having is getting the right one to go to the right side of the browser. It seems to be confused and wants to stay on the left side.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>My Company</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT SRC="jscript/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>
    <? include("include/restocss.php"); ?>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV ID="leftbuttons">
        <DIV CLASS="activitybutton">This is left</DIV><BR>
        <DIV CLASS="activitybutton"></DIV><BR>
        <DIV CLASS="activitybutton"></DIV><BR>
        <DIV CLASS="activitybutton"></DIV>
    </DIV>
    <CENTER>
    <DIV ID="wrapper">
        <DIV ID="header">
            <img src='css/images/logo.png' />
        </DIV><br>
        <DIV ID="navbar">NAVIGATION</DIV>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $(function() {
                    moveScroller();
                });
            </script>
        <DIV ID="content">

        </DIV>
        <DIV ID="footer">

        </DIV>
    </DIV>
    </CENTER><
    <DIV ID="rightbuttons">
        <DIV CLASS="activitybutton">This is right</DIV><BR>
        <DIV CLASS="activitybutton"></DIV><BR>
        <DIV CLASS="activitybutton"></DIV><BR>
        <DIV CLASS="activitybutton"></DIV>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

CSS :

```
{ margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }

body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 background-color: #B99666;
 background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

#wrapper { 
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 800px;

}

#header {
 float:left;
 color: #333;
 width: 705px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 0px solid #ccc;
 height: auto;
 margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
 background: #F2F2E6;
 /*margin-left: 95px;*/
}

.activitybutton{
 color: #333;
 width: 195px;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 0px 0px 5px -11px;
 background: #F2F2E6;
 z-index: 2;
}

#navbar {
 width: 720px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background: #3A451C;
 margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 /*margin-left: 95px;*/
 height: auto;
 float: left;
}

#leftbuttons { 
 color: #333;
 border: 0px solid #ccc;
 /*background: #E7DBD5;*/
 margin: 180px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: auto;
 width: 125px;
 position: fixed;
 float: left;
 z-index: 2;
}

#content {
 float: left;
 color: #333;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background: #F2F2E6;
 margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 800px;
 width: 705px;
 display: inline;
}

#rightbuttons { 
 color: #333;
 border: 0px solid #ccc;
 /*background: #E7DBD5;*/
 margin: 180px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: auto;
 width: 125px;
 position: fixed;
 float: right;
 z-index: 2;
}

#footer { 
 float: left;
 color: #333;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background: #F2F2E6;
 margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 /*margin-left: 95px;*/
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 800;
 width: 705px;
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
}

.logfooter { position:relative; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 5; display:inline-block; } 
.footerbranch { position:relative; bottom: 232px; left: 702px; z-index: 1; display:inline-block; } 
.navlogbottom { position:relative; bottom: 232px; left: 702px; z-index: 4; display:inline-block; }
```

The div in question is the "rightbuttons" div

Comment: Please add a fiddle or something of that nature, we don't need to dig through the entire websites html/css.

Comment: You have float: left; in your #rightbuttons declaration? Shouldn't that be float right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually grabbed and entirley different .css file (old) and not even the right one. In the new one it has been changed to float:right;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `right: 0;` since you are using `position: fixed;`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/CYy5H/5/show/)

```
#rightbuttons { 
  color: #333;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  /*background: #E7DBD5;*/
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  margin-left: 1154px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: 195px;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see there was a position: fixed on there so yes using a right 0 is 100% good

Comment: wouldnt having that div fixed take it out of the document flow? removing position fixed and having float right seems cleaner to me

Comment: That would be cleaner and more elegant but he had position fixed already so I am assuming that he wants that element fixed to the right side of the screen so it scrolls with the page like the left side is. A reply from the OP would clear this up for all of us.

Comment: This solution seemed to work, although say when I hold ctrl and zoom out of the page it seems to slide over to the left. This isn't an issue but if it's at all possible to keep it from doing so that would be great. Thanks for the prompt replies everyone, I didn't realize how fast the community here responded. EDIT: Seemed to have fixed that issue (no idea how) Thanks!

Comment: This is a great community and an excellent tool for developers so I recommend building your rep up from time to time, don't forget to try and help others as we have helped you! I will check into your second question and let you know what I find.

Comment: I added a margin on the right side (because it was going under the scroll bar) and it seems to have stopped doing that. It's working great, thanks.

Comment: No problem, another thing you can do is add `min-width: addAllElementsWidthTogether;` to the body to prevent them from overlapping. If this is the answer then please check it as the right one and best of luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not confused, it's doing what you are telling it to do.  In your selector for `#rightbuttons` you have `float: left;`

Change it to `float: right;`

```
#rightbuttons { 
 color: #333;
 border: 0px solid #ccc;
 /*background: #E7DBD5;*/
 margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 margin-left: 1154px;
 margin-top: 180px;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px;
 height: auto;
 width: 195px;
 float: left;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

Needs to be....

```
#rightbuttons { 
 color: #333;
 border: 0px solid #ccc;
 /*background: #E7DBD5;*/
 margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 margin-left: 1154px;
 margin-top: 180px;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px;
 height: auto;
 width: 195px;
 float: right;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Me either =D  I always miss things -.-

Comment: You write it so much for 8 hours a day that it naturally just all starts to blur together ha.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating these, I would recommend you use the top, left, right properties and removing the margins to position them exactly where you need them (floating right will position the right buttons lower than the left buttons vertically).

```
#rightbuttons { 
    right:8px;
    top:180px;
    margin:0;
}

#leftbuttons { 
    left:8px;
    top:180px;
    margin:0;
}
```